# How can I update a winform asynchronously?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, delegates, asynchronous

I've got a winform, and a bluetooth connection with a lego nxt brick. Now I want to update the form every second to read sensors or the battery level. But if I start a new thread for that, there i a invalid thread operation exception when the thread wants to set the label text.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update the label only from the thread that created it and by the looks of it you are trying to update it from the worker thread.

Have a look at the method [Control.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5kdt95.aspx) and take it from there. There are other methods like [Control.EndInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbdewc0s.aspx) and [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30s4t80c.aspx) and also the property [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a82t6122.aspx), that will be helpful in this context as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke your label updates back to the main thread

see [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604732(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Note that he is in WinForm not a WPF based one.

Comment: You're right. I missed that. I've been stuck in Silverlight/WPF mode for a while now :)